# Is there a way to set up linux to show GUI dialog when program crashes?

Tags: linux, user-interface, error-handling

I am trying to create easy to use linux distro, and i want to show GUI dialog this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNJLk.png
if for example cannot load shared library, or trying to run 64bit program on 32bit. Is there a way to set up linux to do this?

Comment: There is always a way, if you understand [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and of course the documentation of your GUI toolkit. However, I am not sure it would make your Linux distro easier to use, and I believe you would need more than one year of full time work to polish all of it. See also [Linux From Scratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the location,from where you got the program crashed then at that location you can use the
Linux command "notify-send".

notify-send:-
A program to send desktop notifications, inform the user about an event or display some form of information without getting in the user's way.

```
  Syntax:-
```

notify-send [OPTIONS] [body] Key -u, --urgency=LEVEL The urgency level (low, normal, critical).

May be this will help.